# Email format validation in mvc3 view

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In a View in MVC3 I want to make a jquery function which validates a textbox for an email format, but when I want to write it like this:

```
    var a = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
```

It doesn't work, because MVC thinks @(...) its a Razor code.

How can I do it ?

Comment: As I remember double `@`, like `@@`?

Comment: Thank you. I just did it some minutes ago .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor allows you to enter this by typing in double @. Try @@

Comment: I just did it 2 seconds ago:) .. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Raw(" var a = "[a-z0-9....")`