# Difficulty with jQuery Validate "Email" Regex in MVC View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am having a great deal of difficulty with getting an actual regex pattern for an email address in jQuery validate within an ASP.NET MVC view... It seems to be an issue with the "`@`" symbol, but using the suggested "`@@`" does not seem to help, either. The code looks as follows;

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').validate({
                rules: {
                    "Email": {
                        required: true,
                        pattern: "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    "Email": {
                        required: "You must give an email",
                        pattern: "This is wrong."
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}

<form>
 // html form controls, etc.
</form>
```

I cannot seem to get this to validate appropriately, though. If I remove the `@@`, then it throws an error that there has to be a code block. I've tried researching this and found very little help on the subject, which is surprising. The only reference I found was here, which didn't solve the issue: [Email format validation in mvc3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533283/email-format-validation-in-mvc3-view)

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the `email` rule/method built into the plugin?  `email: true`

Comment: I have read through the documentation at least 20 times, and I did not see that. But I went to it and did a Ctrl+F search and sure enough, there is one. That worked just fine. Can you please post this as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `email` rule/method that's included as part of the plugin.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/

```
rules: {
    Email: {  // <- name of the input field
        email: true  // <- user must enter a valid email address
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting to really hate the stack overflow community, as I get another down vote for a question that seems to be one without a lot of previous answers, and is an extremely valid, logical, and common everyday scenario.

Comment: Hey, I just thought you might like to know that I followed the `email` code and found some pretty remarkable stuff. Thanks for pointing it out. It's got some pretty awesome plumbing behind it, that helped me design an `age verification` plugin for jquery validate